# Sphinx failed to read searchd response

Tags: python, sphinx

I have strange behavior of Sphinx searchd. I used it with Python standard client on ubuntu 9.10

For same query it's can give normal response or can give broken package like this:
*failed to read searchd response (status=0,ver=1,len=278,read=72)*

this problem appears with 50% probability.

I have test index with only 5 documents and default config.

Will be grateful for help)

Comment: I figured out this. If Sphinx can't assign user request to worker(if there are no free workers at that time) it return broken package.
This is definitely a bug of searchd.

To fix this, set max_children property to bigger value or to 0(unlimited workers)

Comment: I had the same problem. Found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18314082/1441199).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this. If Sphinx can't assign user request to worker(if there are no free workers at that time) it return broken package. This is definitely a bug of searchd. To fix this, set max_children property to bigger value or to 0(unlimited workers)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but for the benefit of any Googlers coming here....

This can also happen if your sphinx server version does nto match exactly with the API version you are using.